# Kill switch for car to deter theft

Tags: usb, switches, relay, automotive

I am in the process of making a kill switch for my car and after doing some research I couldn't find the answers that I needed to start the project.

One of the biggest questions I have is: how can I use a USB flash drive paired with an adapter board to act as a toggle switch? I was planning to keep a USB thumb drive on my set of keys and have a USB Type A adapter board hidden somewhere in the cabin which connects to the fuel pump/ignition/main relay.

The idea is one or all of those components listed wouldn't work unless I plug a USB drive into the port, better yet, if anyone has an idea as to how I can get the car to start with only that USB drive I would love to hear it.

Comment: The interrupter needs to be locked under the front hood so that it can’t be hot wired from inside the car.

Comment: Note that if something goes wrong, and the circuit fails, your car will stop at some inconvenient location. Keep in mind the safety risk that your car may not start when you need it.

Comment: USB drives are fickle.  You would also have to learn a tremendous amount about programming and electronics to integrate this in a half ass safe/reliable way.  There would be challenges just selecting the right microcontroller as you would need usb compatibility and you'll either need one capable of an adequately low power mode so you don't drain the battery.  Better yet one that you can cut power to when it's not checking a USB stick.  You could also make your own usb stick with a resistor or signal circuit in it to perform a simpler test and reduce risk of data corruption.

Comment: Just fit a toggle switch hidden under the dash - can work on ignition or fuel pump, a classic solution. There are questions about this so do some research.

Comment: yeah, the whole idea of the kill switch is that it make the theives think your car is a dud and go and steal someone else's car, you need to have a car that looks a little disreputable to start with.

Comment: Thanks for all the great responses guys, think I may have been a bit over my head with this idea but it didn't hurt to throw it out there to see the feedback while learning something new. 

@SolarMike I've looked around a bit and have seen a lot of DIY pertaining to that method, I was hoping to take it a step above but that may be the most viable solution thus far.

Do you guys have any suggestions other than the ol' toggle switch idea or is that just the best way to go about something like this?

Comment: If I wanted to steal a car, I would turn up with a low loader and when I was in the business no one ever asked for proof when I collected a car - fit as many switches as you like they will take it if they want it.

Comment: @SolarMike I totally get that, its the same idea as saying the safest way to prevent someone from driving away with your car is to take the engine out every time its parked. My goal isn't to make the car entirely foolproof from being stolen (although I wish I could), but more so to minimize the amount of ways it can be taken under normal circumstances.

Comment: To minimize the risk of your car being stolen, you "simply" need to extend the time needed to do so. It's always the same, with thefts, burglars, and so on. Criminals commonly need to be fast or they get caught. The toogle switch at an uncommon place should be enough. In situations with lots of time you cannot do anything without breaking your usage heavily.

Comment: You could have the toggle switch also control a loud siren or something if someone tries to start the car without flipping the toggle.

Comment: @HK, or an easily found toggle switch that sets off a siren when flipped

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use the USB option for the security switch, personally I would keep it simple by rewiring the USB dongle to just contain a link between two pins.
Effectively acting as an unrecognisable switch, linked to a relay.
Let the relay/s do the heavy lifting of isolating items, even in sequence if preferred.

Wiring the relay to stay open once energised would prevent everything shutting down in the event the USB was removed while driving, (or to enable the USB to be inserted and then removed before driving) Shutting down once the ignition was switched off. Although you would still be relying on the relay not failing, but that's no different to other components in the car.

[image: Latching Relay]

In the USB I'd link pin 2 and 3 in the hopes that if it was ever accidentally inserted into a PC it would be less likely to damage it. But that's not a theory I am sure of without researching further.
[image: USB Pinout]
Ideally make sure its never plugged into anything other than the USB port for the car isolator. (also don't plug a genuine dongle into the car USB port)

The USB and Relay would be the most obvious items to break down, but carrying a spare relay, and maybe a spare innocent looking USB buried in the boot would never raise suspicion.

Comment: If I could upvote your post twice I would, thanks for the input I'll put some time in later tonight to go over your diagrams. I'll be in touch if I run into any questions.